# Converting Linq query to expression tree

Tags: c#, linq, .net-core

I have a lambda expression:

```
query = query.Include(e => e.Product);
```

How do I represent `e => e.Product` via an Expression tree so that i can make it dynamically at runtime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can dynamically create such expression like this:

```
// Declare input parameter of dynamically generated lambda expression
var parameterExpr = Expression.Parameter(typeof(e), "e");

// Select desired navigation property that should be included in a query result
var propertyExpr = Expression.Property(parameterExpr, "Product");

// Generate expression to cast value of this property to type Object. This is
// not strictly needed (if you know type of included property at compile-time).
var convertExpr = Expression.Convert(propertyExpr, typeof(Object));

// Create lambda expression. Thanks to previous "Expression.Convert",
// we can cast lambda to Expression<Func<e, Object>> instead of 
// Expression<Func<e, Product>> (because since you want to create expression
// dynamically, type of Product property is not necesarilly known at compile-time)
var lambdaExpr = (Expression<Func<e, Object>>)Expression.Lambda(convertExpr, parameterExpr);

// Use generated expression in a query
query = query.Include(lambdaExpr);
```

BTW: `EF Core` (and possibly `EF6` too, but I don't have experience with it) has overload of the `.Include()` method that takes property name as an argument, so you actually don't need to generate expression tree at all:

```
query = query.Include("Product");
```

Comment: Thanks. This worked perfectly. I had something close prior. This is not EF but NPOCO related.

Answer (score 0):

As you didn't provide your types I created my own, so your expression will look a little different.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    class Product
    {

    }

    class Shop
    {

    }

    class SomeEntity
    {
        public Product Product { get; set; }
        public Shop Shop { get; set; }
    }

    class MyDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<SomeEntity> Entities { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        private static Expression<Func<SomeEntity, Object>> GetExpression()
        {
            // a stupid random strategy
            if (DateTime.Now.Ticks % 2 == 0)
            {
                Expression<Func<SomeEntity, Object>> expression = e => e.Shop;
                return expression;
            }
            else
            {
                Expression<Func<SomeEntity, Object>> expression = e => e.Product;
                return expression;
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var dbContext = new MyDbContext();

            IQueryable<SomeEntity> query = dbContext.Entities;

            var expression = GetExpression();

            query = query.Include(expression);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Question asks you to create expression dynamically, ie. when you don't know property (`Product`) at compile-time and only get name of the property as an input parameter. Your solution is completely static, you just moved declaration of expression to separate local variable (`expression`), but it doesn't change anything (such variable is actually likely to be optimized-out by compiler in Release build).

Comment: @Ňuf I'm not sure if you're right. OP didn't specify what he means by "dynamic". In my example OP can provide the expression dynamically (e.g. via strategy pattern). I modified the answer to use a simple strategy.